# special character being extracted using scrapy

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I am a beginner at data scraping, I am currently scraping the `quotes to scrape` website using scrapy.

My issue is when I scrape the text in the div box, I use the code `text = div.css('.text::text').extract()` to extract the paragraph. However, when I store the text in the `.csv` file it treats the double quotes as special characters and then misinterprets the double quotes and changes it into some other character.

How can I put an if condition so that those double quotes arent stored during the extraction the extraction?

```py
class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'   #***spiderName***    #THESE 2 VARIABLES MUST HAVE THESE NAME EVERYTIME UR WRITING A SPIDER AS THE SCRAPY,SPIDER CLASS WE INHERIT        
    start_urls = [       #EXPECTS THESE TWO VARIABLES TO BE AVAILBLE IN THE FILE
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
    ]
    
    def parse(self, response):      #response variable will store the source code of the webpage we want to scrap      
      items = QuotetutorialItem()   #Creating an instance of the class created in the items.py file
      allDiv = response.css('.quote')
      for div in allDiv:
         text = div.css('.text::text').extract()    #goes into the .text class to get the text
         authors = div.css('.author::text').extract()   #goes into the .author class to get the text of the author
         aboutAuthors = div.css('.quote span a').xpath('@href').extract()     #goes into the .quote div, then into the span and then gets the <a> tag from all of the boxes in the .quote div and then gets the link using xpath
         tags = div.css('.tags .tag::text').extract()
         
         items['storeText'] = text           #the names passed in the list iterator should be the same- 
         items['storeAuthors'] = authors     #- as the names of the member variables in the items.py file
         items['storeAboutAuthors'] = aboutAuthors
         items['storeTags'] = tags
         
         yield items
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the quotes starts and ends with `“` and `”` characters, you could consider this approach:

- Remove the first and last character from the string.

[Example](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/HNj8IvQGG3L):

```
# Sample quote:
quote_sample = "“A woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it's in hot water.”"

# Modify the string - by taking all the characters after the first and before the last character: 
quote_sample = quote_sample[1:-1]

# Print the modified quote:
print(quote_sample[1:-1])
```

Result - the quote *without* the `“` and `”` characters:

```
A woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it's in hot water.
```

---

After getting the quote, you can then replace the `“` and `”` characters.

Code:

```
quote_sample = quote_sample.replace("“", "").replace("”", "")
```

Comment: thankyou, that is a good approach, but i would like to know how to remove ` “ and ”` so that i can remove it when it comes in a sentence in between somewhere

Comment: @FaizanUlHaq *not the best alternative, in my opinion*, but, you could then replace the characters. I've edited my answer.